# Error: Invalid provider configuration alias

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

After upgrade to version Terraform v0.12.0 and updating config using "terraform 0.12upgrade"

I get error below for terraform init

the alias are set to variables in main.tf and are passed in from azure or substituted.

> There are some problems with the configuration, described below.
>
> The Terraform configuration must be valid before initialization so
>   that Terraform can determine which modules and providers need to be
>   installed.
>
> Error: Invalid provider configuration alias
>
> An alias must be a valid name. A name must start with a letter and may
>   contain only letters, digits, underscores, and dashes.

```
 `provider "azurerm {
  subscription_id = var.arm_subscription_id
  tenant_id       = var.tenant_id
  alias           = "$${var.myservers_name}"
}`"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some mistakes that you made in the provider code that you provided. The code should change like below:

```
provider "azurerm" {

  version = ">=1.2.0"
  alias = "${var.alias_name}"

  subscription_id = "${var.arm_subscription_id}"
  tenant_id       = "${var.tenant_id}"  
}
```

It seems you use the [Azure Provider: Authenticating using the Azure CLI](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/auth/azure_cli.html). You need to use the code like `"${var.var_name}"` when you want to quote the variables that set already.