# Monitor services in azure

Tags: azure, terraform

The error message is:

> There are some problems with the configuration, described below. The Terraform configuration must be valid before initialization so that Terraform can determine which modules and providers need to be installed.

Here's what I'm doing:

- Written a terraform script in azvm.tf to create a VM.
- Defined the variables resourcegroup, location, and pub_key in the variables.tf file, and call those variables in the azvm.tf file using string interpolation syntax.
- Created a VM with the following features:

  a) Ubuntu 18.04 server
  b) VM name : any custom name
  c) Admin_username : Any custom name
  d) disable password authentication
  e) size : Standard DS1_v2
  f) Allow traffic for ssh, http, https
  g) use public ssh key generated in the above step

With help of vi command we created variables.tf file as:

```
variable "resourcegroup"
{
default = "user-pbtwiiiuofyu"
}
variable "location"
{ 
default = ["East US"]
}
variable "pub_key"
{ 
default = ["ssh-rsa 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 root@6badb6ae71d1"]
}
```

And vi command we created azvm.tf file as

```
az vm create -n Myuyuuy5Vm -g var.resourcegroup --ssh-key-values var.pub_key
```

We have another similar task but less easy in compare to it i.e.-

- Write a terraform script in azmonitor.tf to create a storage account,
  storage container, storage blob to monitor and send log reports
  everyday.
- Define the variables resourcegroup and location in the variables.tf
  file, and call those variables in the azmonitor.tf file using string
  interpolation syntax

variables.tf as-

```
variable "resourcegroup"
{
default = "user-pbtwiiiuofyu"
}
variable "location"
{ 
default = ["East US"]
}
```

azmonitor.tf we had created as-

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = var.resourcegroup
  location = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                = "sa123321123"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.location
  sku                 = "Standard_LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_container" "example" {
  name                = "sc123321123"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  account_key         = azurerm_storage_account.eample.name
  public_access       = "blob"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "example" {
  name                = "sb123321123"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  account_key         = azurerm_storage_account.eample.name
  source              = azurerm_storage_container.name
}
```

Comment: I think you've got the wrong concept here. So it seems you're mixing two different ways of creating a VM first one is using terraform - which is what you've been tasked to do and another way to create a VM is using the Az CLI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as mentioned above, you're using a mix of Terraform and Az CLI here - this is not right. You should use one or the other.

It seems you've been tasked to create a Linux VM using Terraform. You need a 'main' Terraform file for your main code/terraform objects and then a 'variable' Terraform file for your variables. Technically, Terraform will flatten every Terraform file that are in the same directory when you do a Terraform init/plan - this means you could put everything in just one single `.tf` file.

However, for the purpose of the tutorial, it's a good practice to split both so they can be managed easily. [This](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_virtual_machine) is the Terraform code that you would want to use - it will help you create a Linux VM.

For simplicity, I'm putting a sample here that links back to the variables in your `variables.tf`

```
terraform {
  required_version = "= 0.14.10" //change this accordingly
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.55.0"
    }
  }
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = var.resourcegroup
  location = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location 
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "internal"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "example" {
  name                = "example-nic"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.example.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "example" {
  name                = "example-machine"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  size                = "Standard_DS1_v2"
  admin_username      = "Admin_username"
  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.example.id,
  ]

  admin_ssh_key {
    username   = "adminuser"
    public_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub") //put your public key here
  }

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "18.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }
}
```

Once you're done with validating the code above, you'll need two more objects,

1. The [`azurerm_network_security_group`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/network_security_group) that will help you create the rules to allow inbound connectivity to the VM
2. The [`azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/subnet_network_security_group_association) that will help you attach the subnet to the NSG.

Once you have the complete code, then you can run a `terraform init` to initialise the modules, followed by `terraform plan` to verify your plan and finally `terraform apply` to deploy the VM.

For the blob part:

`variable.tf`

```
variable "resourcegroup" {
default = "user-pbtwiiiuofyu"
}

variable "location" { 
default = "East US"
}
```

`azmonitor.tf`

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = var.resourcegroup
  location = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "examplestoracc"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_container" "example" {
  name                  = "content"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  container_access_type = "private"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "example" {
  name                   = "my-awesome-content.zip"
  storage_account_name   = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  storage_container_name = azurerm_storage_container.example.name
  type                   = "Block"
  source                 = "./some-local-file.zip"
}
```

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by that? iI the file name is ok?

Comment: Defined the variables resourcegroup, location, and pub_key in the variables.tf file, and call those variables in the azvm.tf file using string interpolation syntax.

we need to create 2 .tf files

This is main part

Comment: Your variable.tf is correct - your azvm.tf is wrong - you should replace `az vm create -n Myuyuuy5Vm -g var.resourcegroup --ssh-key-values var.pub_key` with the code I provided and then improve on it. :)

Comment: yes this is correct!  However to send logs it will be different, I'm not sure how to achieve that.

Btw for variable `"location"
{ 
default = ["East US"]
}`, change it to `variable "location"
{ 
default = "East US"
}. And if you're satisfied with the answer, please upvote/mark as answer so it helps others who also have similar questions! :)

Comment: $ terraform init
There are some problems with the configuration, described below.

The Terraform configuration must be valid before initialization so that
Terraform can determine which modules and providers need to be installed.

Comment: azurerm_storage_blob correct ar per requirement?

Comment: Ah no I didn't notice that - you should use this one [https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/storage_blob] . Check my code, top part, provider - you need to change it

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect blob also - that should work. You should try to check the code from terraform documentation - it's very helpful

Comment: Page Not Found
This documentation page doesn't exist for version 2.62.0 of the azurerm provider.

Comment: Sorry my mistake - typo. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/storage_blob

Comment: thanks it is almost same as our....but what about error.....$ terraform init There are some problems with the configuration, described below. The Terraform configuration must be valid before initialization so that Terraform can determine which modules and providers need to be installed.

Comment: I'm not too sure, maybe there's something wrong with your directory? You need to put var and the blob tf in the same directory and try terraform init. I tried on my end and it works fine, terraform plan also works.

Comment: this is correct  .... provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

?

Comment: $ terraform -v
Terraform v0.11.2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56300861/error-invalid-provider-configuration-alias

Comment: as per it look like something wrong in it

Comment: Oh yes possible you need to update this depending on the version you are using. Try what they mentioned in the post if it works for you... I'm using version 14 so it's different

Comment: how to upgrade to 0.15.5

Comment: You have to follow the guide https://www.terraform.io/upgrade-guides/0-15.html

Comment: Oh that I'm really not sure, sorry, at the moment it's not possible for me to change terraform version to test, you will need to give it a try